# Table doesn't look right when loaded into a div via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

cladtemplate.php outputs a table (I'm creating output generated specifically for a craigslist ad, which won't allow div tags), but when the table is loaded into the span the rows all get about 5 pixels taller. The same thing happens when I load the contents into a DIV, but if I use an iFrame is comes out looking ok.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

```
<span style="width:850px; height:100px" id="prev"> </span>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var area = 100;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(timer, 4000);
        area += 50;
    })
    function timer(){
        updatePreview();
        $('#prev').load(function () {
            $(this).height($(this).contents().height());
            $(this).width($(this).contents().width());
        });
    }
    function updatePreview()
    {
       $.ajax({

         type: "GET",
         url: 'cladtemplate.php',
         //data: "name=' + name + '&area=' + area,
         datatype: 'html',
         success: function(data) {
              $('#prev').html(data);
         }

       });

    }
</script>
```

edit: Some of the table cells contain pictures that are the same dimensions as the cell. Don't know if that's relevant. I could post the code from cladtemplate.php but it's a ton of lines.

second edit: here's some of the html:

```
<table id="Table_01" width="800" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="33" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="35" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="51" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="80" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="48" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="56" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="48" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="32" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="17" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="11" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="279" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="42" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="18" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="11" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="39" height="0" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
        <td width="0" height="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="800" height="50" colspan="15">
            <img id="cglist_ad_template_01" src="images/cglist-ad-template_01.jpg" width="800" height="50" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="0" height="50" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="199" height="128" colspan="4" rowspan="4">
            <img id="cglist_ad_template_02" src="images/cglist-ad-template_02.jpg" width="199" height="128" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="533" height="58" colspan="8" bgcolor="ececec"><center><font size="6">
_END;
            echo "$" . $price . ", " . $area;
echo <<<_END
        </font></center></td>
        <td width="68" height="104" colspan="3" rowspan="2">
            <img id="cglist_ad_template_04" src="images/cglist-ad-template_04.jpg" width="68" height="104" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="0" height="58" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="533" height="46" colspan="8">
            <img id="cglist_ad_template_05" src="images/cglist-ad-template_05.jpg" width="533" height="46" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="0" height="46" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="201" height="24" colspan="5" rowspan="2">
            <img id="cglist_ad_template_06" src="images/cglist-ad-template_06.jpg" width="201" height="24" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="350" height="18" colspan="4" bgcolor="a1d528"></td>
        <td width="50" height="579" colspan="2" rowspan="18">
            <img id="cglist_ad_template_08" src="images/cglist-ad-template_08.jpg" width="50" height="579" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="0" height="18" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="350" height="250" colspan="4" rowspan="10">
_END;
            echo "<img id=\"cglist_ad_template_12\" src=\"bigollizard.png\" width=\"350\" height=\"250\" alt=\"\" />";
echo <<<_END
        </td>
        <td width="0" height="6" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="119" height="54" colspan="3" rowspan="2">
            <img id="cglist_ad_template_10" src="images/cglist-ad-template_10.jpg" width="119" height="54" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="184" height="43" colspan="3"bgcolor="ececec"><center><font size="4">INFORMATION</font></center></td>
        <td width="97" height="54" colspan="3" rowspan="2">
            <img id="cglist_ad_template_12" src="images/cglist-ad-template_12.jpg" width="97" height="54" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="0" height="43" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="184" height="11" colspan="3" bgcolor="ececec"></td>
        <td width="0" height="11" nowrap="nowrap"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="68" height="501" colspan="2" rowspan="14">
            <img id="cglist_ad_template_14" src="images/cglist-ad-template_14.jpg" width="68" height="501" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="179" height="21" colspan="3" bgcolor="ececec">Bedrooms:</td>
        <td width="104" height="21" colspan="2" bgcolor="ececec">
```

...and so on.

EDIT NUMBER THREE!
here's a screenshot of tops of the two tables produced:
the top is in an iframe and
the bottom is in a span

[image: http://s14.postimage.org/651uhnnq9/Untitled.png]

Comment: the varying heights in the td's will not be respected

Comment: they are no longer respected when the container is a div or span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer to my problem here:

http://doctype.com/my-table-td-height-larger-than-specified-height

To quote the answer I got there:

> The issue is that Gmail has a doctype that sets browsers to render in Standards Mode rather than Quirks Mode, like many other e-mail clients. One of the differences in Standards Mode is that an  tag's display property defaults to "inline" and the whitespace around it is considered to be text around the image. The problem this creates is that if your image is squeezed by the table from the left and right side, the spaces move to the bottom.
>
> One solution is to use CSS to set the display of images to 'block'. Since e-mail clients typically wipe blocks, you'll need to use inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind to the `load` event for elements that have a URL, like an image or script element.

So:

```
    $('#prev').load(function () {
        $(this).height($(this).contents().height());
        $(this).width($(this).contents().width());
    });
```

Probably isn't firing since `#prev` is a container (I'll assume a DIV). I'm not sure if that's the stem of your issue but it's something to be aware of.

Seeing the HTML output by `cladtemplate.php` would be helpful.

Comment: @happytimeharry See the `Note:` at the top of the page you linked-to. If you pass `.load()` a function it binds to the `load` event, basically: `.load(function () {})`, maps to this in jQuery 1.7: `.on('load', function () {});`

Comment: doh! your totally right... i read right over that... time for me to go home